# Wix Velo JavaScript: How to create sticky tab headings?

Tags: javascript, tabs, velo

I'm using Wix's tabs element as shown and I want to make it so when I scroll down, the headers of the tab are sticky and scroll down with the information below. This is a sample, so there is more information to be added under the tabs, and it would be easier to have the headings scroll down while the user scrolls down. I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this through Velo, which is the JavaScript interpreter Wix uses. Here is the API for tabs: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/tabs
[Wix's default tabs feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoGL0.png)

I've tried using my own HTML, CSS, and JS samples to see if i could use my own tabs, but im not that familiar with website code and Wix makes it kind of a pain to incorporate all of these together.